# CSS, firefox nao reconhece fonte Bree Serif

Tags: html, css, css3

Uso sources do google, porem obtive a surpresa hoje em que fui testar meus arquivos no firefox e percebi que a fonte nao era carregada. Veja

http://jsfiddle.net/xrckh1db/

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bree Serif';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Bree Serif'), local('BreeSerif-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/breeserif/v5/0daoUMW28nkWOnFz2G4AAgsYbbCjybiHxArTLjt7FRU.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
```

}

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Bree Serif'), local('BreeSerif-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/breeserif/v5/LQ7WLTaITDg4OSRuOZCpswsYbbCjybiHxArTLjt7FRU.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
div {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    }
```

Comment: Esse negócio de local é complicado, falam que economiza banda se a pessoa tiver a fonte, mas nada garante que seja a mesma. E outra, linkar direto pra URL do google não é garantido que vá sempre funcionar (como vc percebeu). O google trabalha com @includes. Se não quer usar includes, copie a fonte pro seu servidor (e veja se é permitido na licença).

Comment: Aqui abre bem em varios browsers. O problema também é que vc está disponibilizando em um formato só.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seja mais interessante utilizar o *Quick-use*, como o Google indica. Não coloco minha mão no fogo mas acredito que dificilmente você terá um problema de carregamento pelo "Google estar *offline*".

As três formas de importação descritas no [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts):

---

#### Padrão: Importando diretamente no HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <style>
      .minha-fonte {
        font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class='minha-fonte'>StackOverflow</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Importando no CSS com `@import`

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

.minha-fonte {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='minha-fonte'>StackOverflow</h2>
```

---

#### Importando com Javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Bree+Serif::latin' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
                  '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <style>
      .minha-fonte {
        font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class='minha-fonte'>StackOverflow</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```